# get wrong url in form action php

Tags: php, forms

on my edit from page i get url `http://localhost/cart_simple/admin/productEdit.php/?edit_id=47`
now when i edit my from and submit i want to go to next page via form action 
here is my form to move to query.php i use form action=query.php and then click on update button

```
 <form name="prdct_frm"  action="query.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <ul>
      <li><lable name>Name:</lable><input type="text" name="prd_name"  value="<?php echo $fillvar[0]['name'];?>"/></li>
      <li><lable name>Price:</lable><input name="prd_price" type="text" value="<?php echo $fillvar[0]['price'];?>"/></li>
      <li><lable name>Qty:</lable><input type="text" name="prd_qty"  value="<?php echo $fillvar[0]['quantity'];?>"/></li>
      <li><lable name>Product image</lable><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></li>
      <img src="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]).'/product_image/'.$fillvar[0]['prod_image'];?>" height="80" width="80"/>
      <li><input type="submit" name="update"  value="Upate Product"/></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

but when i press button i get wrong url.
right url should be `http://localhost/cart_simple/admin/query.php`

and i get wrong url `http://localhost/cart_simple/admin/productEdit.php/query.php`

Comment: change `action="query.php"` to `action="/cart_simple/admin/query.php"`

Comment: Read up on [full and relative paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)).

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
<form action="/cart_simple/admin/query.php">
```

Since you are using **Pretty URLs**, you are getting the relative URL to the current file, which is treated as a folder. So, changing the way of referring your URL to absolute URL might fix this issue.

Now, if you give `/cart_simple/admin/query.php`, it takes from the root. In any case of your URL being any of the below:

```
http://localhost/cart_simple/admin/productEdit.php/
http://localhost/cart_simple/admin/productEdit.php
http://localhost/cart_simple/admin/productEdit
```

It always goes to `/cart_simple/admin/query.php`. Hope it is clear.

Comment: is it secure to do so?

Comment: There's nothing related to security here. What do you fear?

Comment: There are indeed no security issues to be afraid of here.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are appended after the last `/` of the current URL (before the query string).

Since you have a `/` after the `.php`, it gets appended after that.

You can either:

- Not link to `.php/` (risky, third parties might link there)
- Use an absolute path (i.e. start with `/` then include the whole path for the action)
- Test, in `productEdit.php`, which URL has been requested and redirect to the right one if it is wrong.

Comment: can i use like http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]).'/query.php                                                             also let me know about 'Test, in productEdit.php, which URL has been requested and redirect to the right one if it is wrong.' and other errors in my form please